# AWK to replace HTML tag with another and keep text

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I am looking for a way to replace a HTML tag with another, but keep the text.

I have a big HTML file, which contains:

```
<span class="desc e-font-family-cond">fork</span>
```

I want to replace `<span>` tag with `<strong>` tag:

```
<strong>fork</strong>
```

Tool doesn't really matter, but I am looking for a CLI way to do it.

I am not looking for a HTML processor, because input is a text file with some HTML code in it (not a clean/valid HTML) and I am manually working with the output (copy, modify, use later in its final place). I just want to save some time with the replace.

Comment: What does "Replace tag with tag" mean?

Comment: @JNevill, I forgot to add an example, I updated the question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus sometimes I think it is allowed, see the extended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
<span class="desc e-font-family-cond">fork</span>
```

then

```
sed -e 's/<span[^>]*>/<strong>/g' -e 's/<\/span>/<\/strong>/g' file.txt
```

output

```
<strong>fork</strong>
```

Explanation: firstly replace `span` starting using `<strong>`, secondly replace `span` closing using `</strong>`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Python and a tool like BeautifulSoup to handle HTML. Trying to parse HTML with other tools like `sed` or `awk` can lead to [terrible places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

As an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li><span class="desc e-font-family-cond">fork</span>')
for spanele in soup.findAll('span'):
    spanele.name = 'p'
html_string = str(soup)
print(html_string);
```

That's lightweight and pretty simple and the html is handled properly with a library that is specifically built to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AWK for processing HTML files. If you can turn your HTML file into an XHTML file, you can use xsltproc for an XML transformation as follows:

trans.xsl file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span[@class='desc e-font-family-cond']">
    <strong><xsl:apply-templates/></strong>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CLI command for invoking xsltproc, which has to be installed, obviously:

```
xsltproc trans.xsl file.html
```

The standard output of this command is the corrected HTML file as you want to have it.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

`sed 's,<\(\/\)\?span\(\s\)\?,<\1strong\2,g'`

```sh
$ echo '<span class="desc e-font-family-cond">fork</span>' | sed 's,<\(\/\)\?span\(\s\)\?,<\1strong\2,g'
<strong class="desc e-font-family-cond">fork</strong>
```